# FileUtils.mkdir_p doesn't work

Tags: ruby

I have this ruby code:

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p("/Users/naorye/dev/naorye/_site/photography/grid/items/thumbnails")
```

For some reason this does nothing and no exception is thrown..
Do I miss something?

What is the reason for making two aliases mkpath, makedirs to mkdir_p?

Comment: Works fine here.  :)  You sure it's mkdir_p that's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code worked for me. Have you tried running it with the verbose flag?

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p("/Users/naorye/.../thumbnails", :verbose => true)
```

[FileUtils.mkdir_p](http://apidock.com/ruby/FileUtils/mkdir_p) is analogous to the unix shell command `mkdir -p`, which creates the terminal directory *and all intermediate directories* in the path you specify. As for the synonyms `mkpath` and `makedirs`, they're likely there for the same reason `Enumerable` has both `inject` and `reduce`.

Comment: It does create the folder! I am using Jekyll and it seems Jekyll remove the folder right after I create it. Thanks!

Comment: @Naor: verbose means it logs more information about the behaviour of the command/method/whatever. Generally, it gives you a lot more details about what's happening "under the hood", which can be quite handy for debugging a particular piece of code.

Comment: Rails 3.2.22 - In the console, it does nothing and outputs nothing, even with verbose. In the app, verbose does return a single line - "mkdir -p foo/bar/" - in the log - nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Ruby 1.8.7 and it seems that a forward slash in the beginning of the path causes the command to fail for me.  `FileUtils.makedirs("/a/b/c/d")` fails to create the directories and `FileUtils.makedirs("a/b/c/d")` seems to work.